# SmartSVN shows the local state of files to be modified when they are actually unchanged?

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I replaced a few thousand of the files in my working copy, most of which should be identical- however, the local state of ALL of the files replaced is modified even for text files that are clearly unchanged (when I do show changes it even shows a prompt saying the files are equal do you want to show changes anyway). Is there any way to fix the local state of the files? There are thousands so it is not practical to look at them individually.

Comment: Could be a problem of modifications in the line endings. Or even just a modified timestamp. What does "svn status" display?

Comment: Does doing an `svn update` make any difference?